# Proximity profile on bluegiga low energy usb dongle

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on Bluetooth low energy profiles. I am developing the proximity client and server in Bluegiga USB low energy dongle.
I have written Proximity server on one dongle and a Proximity client on another dongle. 
I am able to sent the alert level from client to server. When I am taking the dongles away from each other ( to study the working of the proximity profile) , I am getting 'Link supervision timeout has expired' .
So I would like to know if this timeout information is correct i.e. is it the correct confirmation signal.

Comment: Do you have a link to your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a device recieves disconnection with reason as Link Supervision Timeout, it indicates that the remote device is either out of range or is turned off. Thus the Link Layer waits for "Link Supervision Timeout" time in order to confirm the remote device is no longer connected.

However in Proximity client as per BT-SIG specifications, you application shall calculate the link loss and the path loss [this can be calculated using the remote devices RSSI values] and once the threshold is crossed appropriate alerts needs to be sent to the Proximity Server device. The spec do refers the phenomenon as link loss however it is different from Link Supervision Time out.